# Insert a bold hyphen in a matplotlib title, rather than minus sign?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'd like to insert a bold title with a hyphen. I've tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)
ax.set_title(r"$\bf{hyphenated-example}$")
```

This displays with a minus sign (**hyphenated − example**). I don't think I can use any of the solutions [from this document explaining how to do it in a pure latex environment](https://www.logic.at/staff/salzer/etc/mhyphen/mhyphen.pdf); mbox is not recognised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a bold font by using `weight = "bold"` in your title. Using `ax.set_title("hyphenated-example", weight = "bold")` gives bold text and a bold hyphen (**hyphenated-example**).

Different font weights and font styles are found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/text_props.html).